# What are the general causes of migraine and how can it be treated?

Tags: migraine, headache

what are the general causes of migraine and What is the best way to identify the root cause of migraine?

There seem to be a significant percentage of population suffering from migraine but still I havent seen a scientific way of identifying the root cause of migraine in people. I understand that migraine can be caused by different/multiple reasons but there seems to be no way in identifying the cause of migraine for the individual except for hit and trial method

Comment: Comments deleted. Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 2):

The exact cause of migraines is unknown, although they are thought to be the result of temporary changes in the chemicals and blood vessels in the brain. Some people find migraine attacks are associated with certain triggers, which can include starting their period, stress, tiredness and certain foods or drinks.

There is no cure for migraines, but migraines can be usually treated with:

- **painkillers** – including over the counter medicationssuch as paracetamol and ibuprofen,
- **triptans** – medications that can help reverse the changes in the brain that may cause migraines,
- **anti-emetics** – medications often used to reduce nausea and vomiting.

Many people find that sleeping or lying in a darkened room can also help.

Sometimes a specific trigger can cause migraines, such as stress or a certain type of food (artificial sweeteners, preservatives), so avoiding it can reduce your symptoms.

Read more about [symptoms of a migraine](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/migraine/Pages/symptoms.aspx) and [treating migraines](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Migraine/Pages/Treatment.aspx).

Source: [Migraine](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Migraine/Pages/Introduction.aspx) at NHS